# is there a way to set the settings on an external webcam?

Tags: macos, usb, camera, webcam

I would like to change the brightness settings of a USB webcam. Is there a way to do that without installing extra software on Lion?

Comment: what does your about this mac says about that USB camera?

Comment: https://github.com/Itaybre/CameraController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without - no, not unless your cam manufacturer makes something Mac-specific [but then again, that wouldn't truly be *without*, just *free*].

With - I'd recommend [Webcam Settings](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/webcam-settings/id533696630?mt=12) 8 bucks from the App Store.
It's what turned my Logitech from a barely functional lump balanced on my monitor into something actually useful.